# Counting lowercase letters in a range (column)

Tags: count, excel-formula

I have separated the last letter of individuals names into a separate column in order to count the number of lowercase letters there are in the column. These could be any letter of the alphabet and I want to only count them if they are a lowercase letter. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be very easy to do with a VBA custom function - but as this hasn't been mentioned in your tags, you could use a combination of Sumproduct and Exact to essentially do a case sensitive Countif

```
=SUMPRODUCT(EXACT({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},D1)*1)
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: You could also use the lookup value (the second criterea) as an array - to get a whole count in one